# Shut down process has bad graphics

Tags: shutdown

When I click the shutdown button my computer does the normal logout then goes to a black screen with white text saying its closing some processes.  In the center of the screen are the five dots changing from orange to white to orange like it does at boot, but there's no Ubuntu icon and the dots don't blend in with the black background so something's obviously wrong.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit: I've already tried reinstalling `unity-desktop` and `unity-greeter`.  If there's something like `unity-shutdown` then maybe its a problem with that?  I don't know what's wrong, I just want to fix it.

Comment: If you hit the ESC key during the time when the 5 dots are rotating, it should bring you to a text screen that shows what's happening. Look for any FAIL messages, or processes that are taking a long time to shutdown.

Comment: The 5 dots are superimposed on top of the text screen that shows what's happening.  Text screen always shows as do the 5 dots, as if the text screen is hidden behind the dots and purple screen but it forgot to draw the purple.  I don't really know what's wrong but its annoying and I'd like to fix it

Comment: Well, you have to give me more information. What does the text say? Can you take a screenshot with your phone and then edit your question and add the text and the screenshot? If left alone long enough, will it eventually shutdown?

Comment: Yes it shuts down fine it just looks awful and I don't have a camera so I can't do what you said

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us **something** to go on. What does the text say?

Comment: Just normal computerish stuff about how its shutting down now and it needs to stop some processes before it shuts down then it closes the processes then it shuts down

Comment: Guess we can't help you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem myself.  In the GRUB boot loader I selected `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and I launched the recovery mode version of the newest kernel there.

After it loaded, I selected **resume normal boot**.  I did a restart once the OS loaded, and now I no longer have a problem with my system shutdown.